# Sync Google Fit to Samsung Health using health connect

Tags: google-fit, healthconnect

i was trying to sync the record from google fit to samsung health using the google health connect.

what i understand that i should be able to upload my health records from google fit to samsung health but my both apps is not showing the same record

Please help

thanks